# I need some help with some TF2 controls for PC

Tags: team-fortress-2

Ok so Saturday I downloaded Team Fortress 2 from steam onto my Acer laptop. Well my friend, Austin, has the game as well. I saw him using a wired 360 controller to play the game. But, when I tried, I could only use the controller to pause, select and cancel stuff. It would not let me use it to move around. How do I enable this? Second, I always see people using in-game chat to talk. I know how to use basic in game chat but I do not know how to use the chat window. (I know I am only allowed to ask one question, but please bear with me here. I am trying to learn the game and I never know when my internet will go out.)

Comment: if it helps any I use the default settings

Answer (score 4):

TF2 isn't set up to use an XBox 360 controller by default.  Instead, you need to open a developer console (using `~`, the key left of 1) and type `exec 360controller`

If you ever want to undo this, you need to go back to the developer console and run `exec undo360controller`.

If `~` doesn't work, you may need to enable the Developer Console in the game's Advanced Options menu, activated through one of the buttons at the bottom-right area of the main menu.

Edit:

As for text chat, it's `Y` for all chat and `U` for team-only chat.  Voice chat is done by holding down `V` by default.  Who can hear voice chat is dependent on the server's `sv_alltalk` (off by default) and `tf_teamtalk` (on by default) settings.

Comment: Incidentally, this [also works in other Source games](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1445-TKCN-0831).

Comment: hey thanks for this. I cannot play pc controls. it is like learning latin sign language to me.